# The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.9.

With `render_to_string` I can easily pass rendered html as json to my clientside script. However, since  the template rely on variables such as `user`, I need to also pass the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`, otherwise the template will not know what `request.user` is, so `if` statements break, etc.

However I am getting this deprecation warning:

> RemovedInDjango110Warning: The context_instance argument of
>   render_to_string is deprecated. response_data['content'] =
>   render_to_string("profile/userprofile_detail/content.html", context,
>   context_instance=RequestContext(request))

What is the non-deprecated way to pass `RequestContext` in a `render_to_string`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`render_to_string`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) has a context argument, so you can just pass it directly as a dictionary as you would with any other response

```
render_to_string(template_name, context=None, 
                 context_instance=_context_instance_undefined, request=None, using=None)
```

The linked documentation also includes a note encouraging this

> Deprecated since version 1.8:
>
> The context_instance argument is deprecated. Use context and if needed request.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended method is to pass `request` when you call `render_to_string`. Django will then render the template with a request context.

```
render_to_string("profile/userprofile_detail/content.html", context, request=request)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Finally something that works with Django 1.10+. :)

This should be the correct answer, I believe.