# RemovedInDjango110Warning: The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

For one of the apps, I'm overloading the "delete selected objects" method in a Django 1.9.x project which uses the Admin panel. For that, I have a code similar to this:

```
from django.contrib.admin import helpers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

class MAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['delete_selected']

    def delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        if 'apply' in request.POST:
            # User has confirmed deletion of items
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
        else:
            # User must confirm if they wish to delete selected items
            return render_to_response('admin/confirm_delete.html', { 'queryset': queryset, 'action_checkbox_name': helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The last line produces the following warning in the console:

> .../virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py:45: RemovedInDjango110Warning: The context_instance argument of render_to_string is deprecated. using=using)

I've tried to find some resource that explains how to "update" syntax according to version 1.10.x but I've been unable to.

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488024/the-context-instance-argument-of-render-to-string-is-deprecated) but it's slightly different since the OP is calling `render_to_string` explicitly and I'm not.

How should I update the call above to make the warning disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the "right" way to fix it would be to update it. According to the [documentation, they recommend using `render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#id1)

> Deprecated since version 1.8:
>   The context_instance argument is deprecated. Use the render() function instead which always makes RequestContext available.

If you do want to suppress this warning (highly unrecommended), you can use the `SILENCE_SYSTEM_CHECK` setting.

[More on the system check can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/checks/#core-system-checks)

Comment: Note that this is a Python warning, not a Django system check. You need to use the [warnings module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) to add a filter and ignore the warning.

Comment: Unless really unavoidable, I prefer not silencing alerts, since that is basically postposing the problem. I'd give it a try and get back.

Comment: Correct, suppressing these errors make maintaining the upgrade cycle a nightmare.

Comment: It worked. Simply passing the `request` to the `render()` call and removing the `context_instance` parameter did the trick. Thanks.